# Add a newsletter subscription checkbox form on WooCommrece Register Page

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, sendgrid

I'm using SendGrid plugin which allows to create a Newsletter Subscription Form that will send email notification to subscribe to newsletter (https://sendgrid.com/docs/for-developers/sending-email/wordpress-subscription-widget/).

I want that when a new user sign-up they will have an option to subscribe on newsletter through checkbox on Register Page (http://prntscr.com/nmq8h2).

Comment: Hi Nilambar, my question is. Is there a way to checked if the customer is a new user or a returning user on WooCommerce WordPress using the functions.php file.

Comment: Use this hook `user_register` will fire upon user registration. For more information check this link https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/user_register

Comment: @VigneshPichamani I will test it. Thanks. Hope it will work.

Comment: Hi @LoicTheAztec,

I'm using a SendGridEmail subscription. I want the new sign-up customer will automatically subscribe to my newsletter form. So I created a jquery script and I want that script will only execute for new sign-up user. 

Thanks.

Comment: @LoicTheAztec is there a way to integrate the Sendgrid newsltter subscription on Woocommerce Register page? It is possible?

Comment: @LoicTheAztec just updated the question. My apology.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The SendGrid plugin is not anymore maintained since a while (so it seems really outdated).

**Updated:** Now to add a checkbox for a news letter subscription in Woocommerce registration form (and on My account > Account details section), you will use the following:

```
// Remove "(optional)" label for this checkbox
add_filter( 'woocommerce_form_field' , 'remove_optional_custom_field_label', 10, 4 );
function remove_optional_custom_field_label( $field, $key, $args, $value ) {
    if( 'receive_newsletter' === $key && is_wc_endpoint_url( 'edit-account' ) ) {
        $optional = '&nbsp;<span class="optional">(' . esc_html__( 'optional', 'woocommerce' ) . ')</span>';
        $field = str_replace( $optional, '', $field );
    }
    return $field;
}

// Display a custom checkbox in My Account > Account details
add_action( 'woocommerce_register_form', 'add_account_newsletter_checkbox_field' );
add_action( 'woocommerce_edit_account_form', 'add_account_newsletter_checkbox_field' );
function add_account_newsletter_checkbox_field() {
    woocommerce_form_field( 'receive_newsletter', array(
        'type'  => 'checkbox',
        'class' => array('form-row-wide'),
        'label' => __( 'Subscribe to our newsletter?', 'woocommerce' ),
        'clear' => true,
    ), get_user_meta(get_current_user_id(), 'receive_newsletter', true ) );

}


// Save registration checkbox field value
add_action( 'woocommerce_created_customer', 'save_account_registration_field' );
function save_account_registration_field( $customer_id ) {
    $value = isset( $_POST['receive_newsletter'] ) ? '1' : '0';
    update_user_meta( $customer_id, 'receive_newsletter', $value );

}

// Save checkbox field value for My Account > Account details
add_action( 'woocommerce_save_account_details', 'save_account_details_newsletter_checkbox_field', 10, 1 );
function save_account_details_newsletter_checkbox_field( $user_id ) {
    $value = isset( $_POST['receive_newsletter'] ) ? '1' : '0';
    update_user_meta( $user_id, 'receive_newsletter', $value );
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

---

1) **On WooCommerce Registration form:**

[image]

2) **On My account > Account details *(section)*:**

[image]

> Now as this your plugin is outdated and as the rule on StackOverFlow is one question at the time, you will have to handle the Sendgrid Newsletter integration *(as it's anyway something too broad)*.

Comment: Hi @LoicTheAztec,

I will test it and update you once it is working. Much appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Hi @LoicTheAztec,
The checkbox is displaying, but I don't receive any email notification. I want to stick on Sendgrid Newsletter. 

Thanks,
JM

Comment: Done, my apology.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really get what you are asking. But I do have a few things to point you in the right direction.

1. your `jQuery` should be in it's own file which is loaded using [wp_enqueue_script](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/)
2. Check if a user is loggedin using [is_user_logged_in](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_user_logged_in/)
3. Pass that status to JS using [wp_localize_script](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_localize_script/)
4. you now have the login status available in a JS variable.

Comment: thanks for that. My question is, is there a way to checked if it is a new customer or not. Like if customer is registered the script will execute and if customer used the login form the script will not execute. Thanks.

Comment: My answer will help you get started. If you don't share code what you have tried nobody can see the parts where you get stuck.

Comment: Here is my code. I want that script execute when there is a new user registered.

var email_value = $("input.wpcf7-form-control.wpcf7-text.wpcf7-email.wpcf7-validates-as-required.wpcf7-validates-as-email").attr("value");
            $('input#sendgrid_mc_email').val(email_value);
            if($('input#sendgrid_mc_email').val()!= ''){
                if(window.location.pathname === '/my-account/'){
                    $("#sendgrid_mc_email_submit").trigger("click");
                }
            }