# Update custom user meta value using checkbox

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, account, user-data

I am using *"[Integrate Sendgrid Newsletter Subscription form on WooCommrece Register Page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56072021/integrate-sendgrid-newsletter-subscription-form-on-woocommrece-register-page/56072958#56072958)"* answer code to one of my previous answers. On Woocommerce account details section of My account page, I have a custom user meta field which is `receive_newsletter` which by default has a value of "1" when is checked, like:

[image]

When it is unchecked the value will be empty and make it unchecked.

However when I save the changes it will not update.

This would be supposedly an output:

[image]

Comment: You would need to share example code

Comment: @Ali_k just added the sample code.

Comment: @JmCabugnason You should better delete this question…

Comment: I can't delete it.

Answer (score -1):

Just figured it out why it is not working, I did not check the value. Please use this if anyone having the same issue. `sanitize_text_field()`

Thanks all.

Comment: Sorry but checkbox values doesn't need to be sanitized they just need to be escaped or replaced like [in my updated original answer](Integrate Sendgrid Newsletter Subscription form on WooCommrece Register Page)